# Dropbox and Xcode

Tags: cocoa, xcode, dropbox

I would like to start developing my cocoa app on two different machines.  I'm not sure of the easiest way to achieve this, but was considering using my dropbox folder.  Will xcode be ok with this?  Is this a common approach and does it work well?  Are there some common 'gotcha's I should look out for?

Comment: Please consider using a version control system.

Comment: what would be the benefits of this vs dropbox, and can you recommend anything.  This is a small hobby project, so must be simple and free.

Comment: I'm posting a comment to agree with Justin because just an upvote isn't enough. You should be using a VCS anyway, but working across multiple machines is another thing they are very helpful with.

Comment: @Ben Take a look at Mercurial, Git, and Subversion. I'd reccoment my favorite but that usually turns in to a flamewar...

Comment: If this isn't squarely in the "belongs on superuser.com" camp, it's riding the fence.

Comment: A version-control system enables time-travel, which in turn emboldens you to make deeper changes than you otherwise might, knowing that you can easily go back to an older version if it turns out that the plan you embarked upon is a bad one. Distributed version-control systems make it easy to work on multiple machines, as you can always push from one machine to the other, even when Dropbox is inaccessible for any reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, I'd suggest you use a version control system like [git](http://help.github.com/).

Also, keep in mind that app store distribution signing can fail mysteriously when the project is located inside a Dropbox directory. I made this mistake when I released [Textual](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textual/id364609827?mt=8) and keep paying the price every time I cut a release.

Comment: Why can the distribution signing fail when inside the dropbox folder?

Answer (score 3):

You really should use a version control system, even if inside the dropbox folder - git works well for this.

From my experience, Xcode works fine with Dropbox. Just be sure to not have the project open in more than one location, as Xcode settings will be saved for whichever computer the project is last closed on (even if its not the most recent).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a real version control system is the best solution here. But, if you're going to use Dropbox as a quick-and-dirty fix, do a little reading on the Dropbox forums first. There have been some issues. Here are some relevant threads (http://forums.dropbox.com/tags.php?tag=xcode).

I have used Dropbox in this manner for working on small projects on both my iMac and my MacBook Pro (but not, of course, at the same time) and haven't (yet) had any issues. Both are running 10.7.3 and the latest Dropbox build (v1.2.52). But I stick to a pretty careful protocol. The iMac is the "real" development machine. The MBP is only for coding and testing on the simulator, when I'm away from the iMac. All testing on real hardware (and anything else dealing with certificates and such) only happens on the iMac. All projects are initiated on the iMac, then copied manually to Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use github, unfuddle, or google code.  All have free plans and provide source control and I think unfuddle lets you have private repositories in the free plan.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  I've not used any kind of version control before so I'll go with the simplest first.

Comment: Adding bitbucket to the list, will also allow private repos in the free plan.

Answer (score 0):

I've witnessed first hand some odd (and potentially destructive) behavior with DropBox and source files opened and being edited in Xcode. It looks like a whole range of text around your edits gets deleted or replaced, etc.

I absolutely agree with others, though: Use an SCM. It's not *that* hard and will save you a lot of heart-ache. If all you're looking for is "sync between my workstations" and "let me restore an earlier version" an SCM is far better suited.